# Facebook authentication shows deprecated method error

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the Facebook C# SDK and trying to authenticate my user. The first part sort of worked, my app showed me the facebook login page inside a browser control.

This is the code I have, I was following [this example](http://igrali.com/2012/06/05/facebook-authentication-from-windows-phone-app/).

```
    private readonly FacebookClient _fb = new FacebookClient();

    private void Browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var loginUrl = GetFacebookLoginUrl();
        BrowserControl.Navigate(loginUrl);
    }

    private Uri GetFacebookLoginUrl()
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["client_id"] = FacebookSettings.AppID;
        parameters["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        parameters["response_type"] = "token";
        parameters["display"] = "page";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FacebookSettings.ExtendedPermissions))
            parameters["scope"] = FacebookSettings.ExtendedPermissions;

        return _fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
    }
```

After I filled in my details to log into facebook, I got this error:

[image]

Any idea's which method is deprecated and how I can fix this?

Comment: The blog you're referring to is mine, and this code works for me in emulator, test app and the app I have published on the Marketplace (Photo Light). The cause may be if you're using parameters["display"] = "touch"; anywhere when communicating with Facebook.

Comment: I was originally trying with display set to `touch`. It still didn't work after switching to `page` but restarting VS fixed the problem.

Comment: Great, glad it works for you now! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same code and it's working. And such an error is occuring because of a bug in the facebook API, when display parameter is set to "touch" or "wap". That shouldn't occur when using "page". Try using "popup" as the display.

Try changing the july 2012 Breaking Changes in the app's advanced settings tab(in developer.facebook.com). Refer to [this link](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2012/04/09/1220/) for information on this issue. And [similar issue](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/355102764525510) in facebook developer site.